# Checking iMessage Functionality in ios during RunTime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, sms

I am allowing users to send a message to recipient. But i need to check the recipient iphone os version, if it is ios 5, then i have to send an iMessage, else it should send normal message. How can i check that programmatically.

Comment: Shouldn't the system handle this for you?

Comment: oh...then i don't need to check the ios version...good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Messages framework to display view controllers to let your users send messages, the system controllers will help you figure out whether to send a regular SMS or an iMessage. So all you need to do, really, is to ask to compose a new message to the appropriate recipient.